# Pandas dataframe replace column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame, and I need to replace column values.
So I tried the following but not working as expected:

```
dict_by_nationality = {
            250:0, #'Some-Nation locality', 
            260:0, #'Some-Nation locality'
            270:0, #'Some-Nation locality'
            280:0, #'Some-Nation locality'
            290:0, #'Some-Nation locality'
            440:0, #'Some-Nation locality'
            450:0, #'Some-Nation locality'
            460:0, #'Some-Nation locality'

             310:0, #'Other-Nation locality'

            510:2, #'Other place',
            520:2, #'Other place',
            530:2, #'Other place',
            }

# dat['my column'].apply(dict_by_nationality.get)
# dat['my column'].map(dict_by_nationality).fillna(dat['my column'])
dat['my column'].replace({310: 0}, inplace=True)
print(dat.head())
```

Getting None values!!

## Update

I realized that doing the replace on the same dataframe was overwriting it, there was a need for saving it to another variable and then do the replacement.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example to reproduce your problem? How is `dat` created?

Comment: Just a pro-tip, if you need help with Pandas, copy/paste de dataframe rather than attaching a screencap of it. This way, we can just copy it and offer a solution.

Comment: It's complicated, it's a merge between 3 data frames and I'm working with local csvs... so I cant see how you can run it :~, but I'll try

Comment: Please make a dummy dataframe with a few rows and columns and then show your expected output on that one. We don't need your data to be as is. But you would be benefited more often, if your dummy data is small and portrays what you want to do, rather than showing your actual data.

Comment: I deployed it to : https://github.com/zbeedatm/machine_learning

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

Try using the following (`df[col].str.strip().str.replace()`) as this will take care of situations when you have unidentified whitespaces in your dataframe.

```py
dat['my column'].str.strip().str.replace('310', '0')
```

I think one of your commented out lines should work fine. Try the following with the dummy data I made for this purpose.

**Suggested Solution**

```py
df[col].map(dictionary).fillna(df[col])
```

### Example

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': list('abcde'), 'b': list('abacd')})
df.a.map({'a': 'A', 'b': 'B'}).fillna(df.a)
```

**Output**:

```sh
0    A
1    B
2    c
3    d
4    e
```

Comment: there's no `inplace` keyword for it. Made the change. Pro tip: also check documentation.

Comment: changed it to dat['צורת יישוב שוטפת'].str.strip().str.replace('310', '0'), but didnt help!

Comment: There was a small typo. I dropped the dict.

Comment: As I mentioned, it's compiling but still getting None in result

Comment: Try with the dummy data I posted here. We don't have access to your data. We can only solve a similar problem. You will have to solve the rest.

Comment: I realized where is my problem, i was overriding the dat dataframe vlaue. when using a new name for replacing it's fine: new_dat = dat

Comment: @M_Z please consider **accepting** the answer if it helped.